How do I disable the overlay for simulating secondary displays?
I wish to use scrcpy for the secondary display (simulated from dev options) while not having an annoying overlay on the main display.
I have tried this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/253738
However, it simply disables the secondary display.
I'm on the latest A14 for bluejay.

kindly provide more details on what problem you are facing . Please provide a minimal reproducible example. You should also read How to Ask  and edit your question to improve it.
